# Time complexity of reversed() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the time complexity of reversed() in Python 3?

I think the answer would be O(1) but I want to clarify whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: @Sachin Rawat this answers `reverse`, op is asking about `reversed`

Comment: The time complexity of `reversed` should actually be O(1), because it just returns an iterable, but not a new list

Comment: The time complexity is O(1), but in practice, that rarely matters, because if you are calling `reversed` then you are also iterating over it, which takes at least O(n) time. If you break early from the iteration then it will matter; I don't remember the last time I had to iterate backwards *and* break early, though.

Answer (score 5):

`reversed(some_list)` always takes about 120ns to finish on my machine, which is a clear sign of O(1) time complexity. This is because this function does not actually change any values, it just returns a `list_reverseiterator`, which iterates the list backwards. This object is very similar to a normal generator, as it its elements get consumed, when you are, for example, calling `list` on it:

```
In [10]: a = [i for i in range(5)]

In [11]: b = reversed(a)

In [12]: b
Out[12]: <list_reverseiterator at 0x7f11fe3615b0>

In [13]: list(b)
Out[13]: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

In [14]: b
Out[14]: <list_reverseiterator at 0x7f11fe3615b0>

In [15]: list(b)
Out[15]: []
```

Comment: What is the Space Complexity of ```reversed(a)```?

Comment: @AntonBelsky This should also be O(1), because the size of the generator does not depend on the size of the objects it's iterating over. Otherwise infinite generators would not be possible