# Python reverse() vs [::-1] slice performance

Tags: python, performance

Python provides two ways to reverse a list:

List slicing notation

```py
['a','b','c'][::-1] # ['c','b','a']
```

Built-in reversed() function

```py
reversed(['a','b','c']) # ['c','b','a']
```

Are there any relevant differences in implementation/performance, or scenarios when one is preferred over the other?

Comment: For a real list, `reversed()` just changes the iteration direction; `[::-1]` constructs a whole new list. The impacts are what you'd expect.

Comment: ...so half of this question is duplicative of [time complexity of `reversed()` in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540349/time-complexity-of-reversed-in-python-3). If I can find a duplicate for the other half, about the time complexity of `[::-1]`, the question can presumably be closed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for linking that. I think this question is unique in that it's asking how the two compare to each other, which is useful as a standalone question. Many useful questions on SO could be answered with separate sub-questions that have already be answered, but we allow them as standalones for SEO/pedagogical efficiency.

Comment: [difference between `reverse()` and `::-1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637829/difference-between-reverse-and-1)  has an answer covering the time complexity of `::-1`, and _also_ covering `reversed()`, though it's not directly what the question asks.

Comment: The question is based on a false premise.   `reversed(['a','b','c'])` does not return the result `['c','b','a']` as shown in the comment, it returns an iterator.

Comment: SEO is part of the _point_ of keeping well-asked duplicates in our knowledge base. We get a maximally canonical question as the target (with as many eyes on improving it / adding additional answers as possible), with additional links pointing to it with different keywords; that's part of why questions closed as duplicate can be upvoted (and are protected from automatic deletion should they receive upvotes or a high view count in practice). Even with the question itself being negative right now, having an answer with a positive score may (if I understand correctly) result in retention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slicing operator constructs a new list ***in memory***, which has implications on both memory and runtime.

`reversed`, on the other hand, returns an iterator which simply yields items one after another from the original list in reversed order. It ***does not*** allocate any additional memory.

So if all you're doing is iterating over the list in reverse and there's no need to construct a new (for example if you need to mutate it), then I'd say go for `reversed`.

Comment: "It does not allocate any additional memory." to be pedantic it does: it allocates the memory for the iterator :P

Comment: Can't argue with that ;)