# Performance of reversed() function compared to reversing slice

Tags: python, performance

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998392/python-reverse-vs-1-slice-performance) but there's a slight difference in my question.

I have two functionally identical functions as follows:

```
def count1(text):
    c = 0
    for i, j in zip(text, reversed(text)):
        if i == j:
            c += 1
    return c

def count2(text):
    c = 0
    for i, j in zip(text, text[::-1]):
        if i == j:
            c += 1
    return c
```

I would not expect *count2()* to perform as well as *count1()* on the grounds that there's no new list created - just an iterator.

I have determined empirically that this is true for short strings. However, as the length of the strings increase, the performance characteristics seem to change.

Here's the test rig:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choices
from string import ascii_lowercase

for k in range(2, 21, 2):
    print(f'{k=}')
    text = ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=k))
    for func in count1, count2:
        print(func.__name__, f'{timeit(lambda: func(text)):.4f}')
```

Now consider the output and note that *count1()* is faster than *count2()* for string lengths less than 12. As the string length increases *count2()* runs faster.

The differences are minimal and unlikely to ever be critical. It is however intriguing and I'd like to understand why this might be the case.

**Output:**

```
k=2
count1 0.2870
count2 0.3247
k=4
count1 0.3454
count2 0.3740
k=6
count1 0.4228
count2 0.4518
k=8
count1 0.4799
count2 0.4990
k=10
count1 0.5382
count2 0.5584
k=12
count1 0.6406
count2 0.6426
k=14
count1 0.6792
count2 0.6555
k=16
count1 0.7593
count2 0.7480
k=18
count1 0.8595
count2 0.8335
k=20
count1 0.8538
count2 0.8121
```

**Notes:**

```
macOS -> 13.3
Python -> 3.11.2
CPU -> 3GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
RAM -> 32GB
```

Comment: Maybe it's processor dependent. Running this on my 5700X/Python 3.11 the `count2()` function is always slower (even for k>12).

Answer (score 3):

Strings don't implement `__reversed__`, so they go through the [generic `reversed` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Objects/enumobject.c#L428) that just indexes the sequence with indexes from len(seq)-1 to 0.

On Python 3.11, "compact ASCII" strings have a specialized iterator type that uses a [more efficient `__next__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L15723) taking advantage of the fact that all code points are in the ASCII range.

`text[::-1]` is a compact ASCII string, so iterating over `text[::-1]` uses the specialized ASCII iterator. On the other hand, iterating over `reversed(text)` has to go through the generic `__getitem__` implementation with no special optimizations. Depending on system details like how fast your cache is, this may be enough for `text[::-1]` to get a small advantage in a microbenchmark like this.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you. What I now wonder about is "best practice" in a situation where the developer wants to be platform independent and also has no idea how long the strings might be. Should it be *reversed()* or *[::-1]* as the default technique?